# Understanding of two sentences with "expect"

Tags: word-meaning

I **expect** to do well on the exam. 
She **expects** to go to college.

I looked up in the dictionary, I found "expect" means "to think that something will happen".
So, does the first sentence mean "I think I will do well on the exam"? does the second sentence mean "She thinks she will go to college"?

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. 
Some might say that "expectation" in some cases means a "belief" that something will happen, but that tends more toward "faith" than expectation. One can of course have unrealistic expectations, or faith in something that others consider foolish; but if you think it will happen, you expect it; and if you expect it, you think it will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. But also be aware that "expect (object) to" can imply a demand. So, "I expect you to do as I tell you" does not actually predict that you will obey, only that you will be punished if you don't. As is so often true, context is important.